# Emacs: Gloabally disable flycheck/prettier temporarily

Tags: emacs, macros, eslint, flycheck

I often use rgrep to find files I need to change and then a macro to go through these files, do the change and save it. It's a very neat flow with one downside: I have prettier check each file on save and flycheck (using eslint) also goes absolutely crazy and maxes out my CPU.

So I wondered, if there is any good way to globally (as my macro visits a lot of files) disable temporarily (as I want these modes after the macro finished) certain modes, most importantly flycheck?

I didn't find anything related, any ideas on how this could be done?

EDIT:

This is how I load flycheck e.g. in rjsx-mode:

```
;; disable jshint since we prefer eslint checking
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
              (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
                      '(javascript-jshint)))

;; disable json-jsonlist checking for json files
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
              (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
                      '(json-jsonlist)))


;; use eslint with web-mode for jsx files
(defun my/use-eslint-from-node-modules ()
  (let* ((root (locate-dominating-file
                (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)
                "node_modules"))
         (eslint (and root
                      (expand-file-name "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js"
                                        root))))
    (when (and eslint (file-executable-p eslint))
      (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable eslint))))
(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'my/use-eslint-from-node-modules)
(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'rjsx-mode)
```

(Full emacs config here: https://github.com/phuhl/sheeshmacs)

Thx

Comment: Just a recommnedation, post your question here instead :) [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As flycheck isn't enabled (or even installed) by default, show how you are *enabling* it for these files in the first place, and then someone will likely be able to help.

Comment: @phils, good point, I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your macro to open files with `find-file-literally`. This will always open files in Fundamental mode, preventing flycheck from running (well, assuming you have no flycheck hooks for Fundamental mode.)

See `C-h f find-file-literally` or [Visiting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion! With a little helper function I just wrote, you can easily open files from dired also:

```
(defun dired-find-file-lit ()
  "In Dired, visit the file or directory named on this line."
  (interactive)
(dired--find-file #'find-file-literally (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
```